# SQL query on multiple columns and sort

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and the ZIP code is a field. If I want to get the top 10 in each table, I use the following command.

```
select ZIP, count(*) from tab37 group by ZIP order by count(*) desc limit 10
```

However, I have 3 other tables (tab38, tab39, tab40) and want to include these 3 tables also. How do I write a query to do the same (get the top 10 ZIP codes in all the 4 tables)

Comment: . . Your question is ambiguous.  Do you want 10 rows in your result set or 40?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union all and bracket the queries

```
(select ZIP, count(*) from tab37 group by ZIP order by count(*) desc limit 10)
union all
(select ZIP, count(*) from tab38 group by ZIP order by count(*) desc limit 10)
union all
(select ZIP, count(*) from tab39 group by ZIP order by count(*) desc limit 10)
union all
(select ZIP, count(*) from tab40 group by ZIP order by count(*) desc limit 10)
```

I am assuming that you don't care that a zip code may be present in one or more tables - if you do care then amend your question appropriatly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the top *across* the tables, then take the `union all` *before* aggregating:

```
select zip, count(*)
from ((select zip from table37) union all
      (select zip from table38) union all
      (select zip from table39) union all
      (select zip from table40) 
     ) t
group by zip
order by count(*) desc
limit 10;
```